# create dynamic link to share over the git

Tags: python, symlink

I am writing a script that should push its output files to the git. as some of the files need to be duplicated I used a dynamic link to the src file to the output tree is like:

```
git/base/
git/base/dup_file
git/base/dir/dup_file_link
...
```

But the link links me to the src who created the file, now when I want to push it to the git I get a link to my local repository, where I want to get the link to the git.

I used python command `os.symlink` in the script for creating the soft link.

How do I create something that can be shared over the git?

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative symlink:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/git/base/dir')
os.symlink('../dup_file', 'dup_file_link')
```

Comment: path to git base dir is to the local repository that i use or to another location?
as i understand it, to my local is the current situation, i want to create a link, push it and when some else reads it he'll get the path to his own git, and not mine/

Comment: In the above code `'/path/to/git/base/dir'` can be an absolute path to a dir in your local repository. The `os.chdir` command changes your current working directory. It allows you to call `os.symlink` with *relative* paths.